# Transform the rows of my dataframe from individuals to count by group to perform a treemap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to perform a treemap but I need to transform my dataframe first. My dataframe looks like that:

```
df
People      Country     City     Neighbour 
1              X          Ye        2
2              X          Ye        1
3              X          Ga        5
4              Z          Te        11
5              Z          Ro        29  
6              Z          Ro        2
7              Z          Ro        2
8              Z          Ro        2
9              Z          Ro        2
```

I need to transform my dataframe to this

```
dft
Country     City     Neighbour Count
X          Ye        2           2
X          Ga        5           1
Z          Te        11          1
Z          Ro        29          1
Z          Ro        2           4
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do a simple group by.

```
df.groupby(['Country','City','Neighbor']).count().reset_index()
```